# Can I do pivot with mysql 5.1?

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot

Can I do pivot with mysql 5.1? (or emulate it somehow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1339#78